# regex match urls NOT containing given set of strings

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need to match all urls that DO NOT contain either `/admin/` or `?page=`.

I'll be using this as a redirect rule in an iirf.ini file (supports htaccess syntax).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead `(?!...)` with a regex OR `(a|b)`:

```
^(?!.*(/admin/|\?page=))
```

This is saying that when positioned at the start (`^`) the input should contain either of your two test strings

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot with [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456468/routing-constraints-dont-assign-values-to-a-rails-parameter-correctly-use/24471237#24471237).

Comment: Finally I found it. Thank you for your answer. I was configuring SSL with permanent redirect to https with few urls that should not be forced. Your answer made it work