# Routing constraints don't assign values to a Rails parameter correctly; use '+' to delimit values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I would like to be able to support country codes and region codes in my application's routes.  For example:

- /entities/us
- /entities/us+ca
- /entities/us/mn
- /entities/us/mn+wi+ia
- /entities/us+ca/bc+wa

My current route:

```
  get "/entities/:country_code/(:region_code)" => "entities#index", :constraints => {:country_code=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}[\+\,]?/, :region_code=>/[a-zA-Z]{2}[\+\,]?/}
  resources :entities
```

Trying `/entities/us+ca` results in this exception:

```
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_entity
  @entity = Entity.find(params[:id])
end 

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/entities_controller.rb:79:in `set_entity'

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"us+ca"}
```

I change the route to:

```
get "/entities/:country_code/(:region_code)" => "entities#index"
resources :entities
```

This allows the multiple country and region query to work (i.e. `us+ca` is assigned to the `:country_code` parameter), but this broke the `/entities/new` path--`new` is now considered to be a `:country_code` parameter.

I'm assuming that the problem is related the the regular expressions.

Is there a regex that will work for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regex isn't quite right.  The one you have there will match 2 characters optionally followed by a `+` or a `,`. You need to also allow the subsequent character pairs.

Try this regex: `/[a-zA-Z]{2}(\+[a-zA-Z]{2})*/`  (that matches 2 characters followed by 0 or more sequences of `+` followed by 2 characters).

Comment: My most-recent attempt was `([a-zA-Z]{2}\+)?[a-zA-Z]{2}` which worked for pairs (e.g. `/entities/us+ca/mn+bc`), but not for more (e.g. `/entities/us+ca+nl`).  Thanks a LOT for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this would work

```
get '/entities/*country_code/*region_code', to: 'entities#index', constraints: { country_code: /[a-zA-Z]{2}[\+\,]?/, region_code: /[a-zA-Z]{2}[\+\,]?/ }
```

May need to play with your constraints regex.

Comment: Didn't work; alues (mn+wi) are associated with the `:id` parameter.