# Expand existing regex to NOT match URL part

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, regex-lookarounds

A messy legacy part of a website I am trying to simplify uses *many* URL rewrites for routing. Now I have a problem with a new feature, because rewrites *I* need to use for said feature don't work because of older rewrites, that are essential for the legacy website functionality.

For example, the "new feature" URL `https://www.example.com/new-feature/something` is matched by the legacy rewrite:

`(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$`

... and a few others.

I tried expanding the legacy rewrite with a modified version of a negative lookahead like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521366/regex-match-urls-not-containing-given-set-of-strings):

`^(?!.*(new\-feature))(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$` **EDIT 2:** Is this *syntactically* ok?

... but that broke my feature as well as the legacy part.

How can I expand the legacy rewrites without affecting their functionality?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The system is WordPress, the rewrites are done in the old ["Rewrite" plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/) which is based on the WordPress [WP_Rewrite](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/) class.
I'd be happy to *not* change this, because there are 80+ rules. Sadly, it doesn't look like this plugin respects order and [L] flags – or I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you use these in PHP or Apache mod_rewrite? In Apache I would just put the regex for the new feature before the legacy regex and declare it as last rewrite. In that case the legacy regex is only reached if new feature didn't match before.

Comment: These rules apply to mod_rewrite.

Comment: @FlorianSchwalm Please see EDIT ... it doesn't look like I can declare rewrites as last (you were talking [L] flag, right?).

Comment: Yes, I meant using the [L] flag for Apache mod_rewrite. I'm not familiar with this WP Plugin and it also seems to have been abandonded by its author. I'd recommend to either contact him and see if he wants to provide support or do the dirty job of migrating this legacy part of your application.

Comment: @FlorianSchwalm I know the plugin isn't updated anymore, but it covers a part of WP that's not updated, either (WP_Rewrite was introduced and not changed since WP 1.5.0). The site is an "esoteric" portal and my customer doesn't have much money, so I doubt a migration is feasible here. Thanks for your thoughts, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this hurts a bit, but I want to end this with style ...

E. g. hyphens and slashes in URLs like "/new-feature/something" don't need to be escaped in the mod_rewrite environment. So, if you test regex-es with online tools (which want them to be escaped), remember to remove escape characters for e.g. "-" and "/".

So, my "solution" was to remove the escape characters from my regex-es.

Thanks everyone for having a look, sorry for wasting your time :-/

Cheers